# Find the average over the n last purchases, for every user in the table using SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, average, window-functions

I have a SQLite db with two tables:

#### users

| userID | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |

#### purchases

| purchaseID | userID | price | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 70 | 5166323 |
| 2 | 1 | 30 | 6543654 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | 5456434 |
| 4 | 2 | 30 | 5846541 |
| 5 | 2 | 40 | 9635322 |
| 6 | 1 | 50 | 2541541 |

I want to write an SQL query that returns a table

| userID | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | avgPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |

where avgPrice corresponds the the average price of the user's **n last purchases**.

I managed to write the following query, which calculates the average price of each user's purchases:

```
SELECT
    users.userID,
    users.field1,
    users.field2,
    users.field3,
    users.field4,
    avg(purchases.price)
FROM purchases
JOIN users on users.userID = purchases.userID
GROUP BY purchases.userID
```

But I could not think of any efficient way to calculate the average over the last n purchases. (The only way I could find involved inner queries and was significantly inefficient).

I would appreciate your help solving this problem.
(FYI the tables here are simplified versions of the tables I actually use).

Comment: What are the columns field1, field2, ...? Do they have anything to do with your requirement?

Comment: Why have you not provided any sample data for the field columns, do you even need them to illustrate your question? Probably your *Purchases* table is only required. Please provide actual desired results, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank the purchases starting from the last one and then join to the table `users` to aggregate:

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(AVG(p.price), 0) avgPrice
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
  FROM purchases
) p ON p.userID = u.userID AND p.rn <= ?
GROUP BY u.userID
```

Change `?` to the number **n** that you want.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! By the way, if I wanted the output table to also include a column with the last purchase timestamp, would I need to change? I tried to add p.timestamp to the list of columns at the beginning, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ido use `MAX(p.timestamp)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT AVG(p.price)
        FROM (SELECT p.price
              FROM purchases p
              WHERE p.userID = u.userID
              ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC
              LIMIT ?    -- whatever number you wnat
             ) p
        ) as avg_price
FROM users u;
```

For performance, you want an index on `purchases(userID, timestamp desc, price)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually wanted to avoid inner queries because they slow down the performance significantly. But I did not think of using an index, which is a great idea.